# Would the Adafruit USB Audio Adapter be sufficient for Pi 3 B+ audio?

Tags: audio, audio-playback, pi-3b+, usb-audio

I have a Pi 3 B+ and overall it's really good but has one glaring defect: the audio from the audio jack with a set of (non-HDMI) external speakers is total and utter garbage, distorted almost beyond recognition. (I found a few software fixes but none were effective.) Would this inexpensive USB converter from Adafruit be adequate to solve my problem?

[USB Audio Adapter - Works with Raspberry Pi](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1475?gclid=Cj0KCQjwuYTYBRDsARIsAJnrUXCNglnc_aUM5S5tvRgjiHgZ1dJfo90cnpQw2JinNX3ejbOG9RjoPEMaAu11EALw_wcB) (adafruit.com)

[image]

...or do I need something more complex and expensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that converter should be enough to give you good audio - at least it should make the audio sound like what it's supposed to sound like. Of course, you get what you pay for, and if you wanted stunning hd audio, you would have to invest in really good speakers and an even better converter. But for normal applications, that should be fine.

Just note it will not be plug and play - there will be a small amount of setup, which should be pretty easy.

Comment: All I want is to play .ogg files and stuff so the Makerspace isn't dead quiet. This should be fully adequate.